# job-type syntax issue

Tags: quartz.net

In 
`<job-type>namesapcename.jobclass,--------</job-type>`.

What should be there in place of `-------` and if job-type is like 
`<job-type>namespace1.namespace2.namespace3.Jobclass,----------------</job-type>` then what should be in place of `--------------`
Also please tell me this concept or behind the scene logic of writing in such a way.

Thanks in advance,
Akki J

Comment: SO works that if someone answers your questions and you're happy with it, you should accept it. I've answered another of your questions before but you didn't even bother replying or thank me. That's very unfair.

Answer (score 1):

That should be the Assembly name:

```
<job-type>Fully.Qualified.Type.Name, AssemblyNameWithoutTheDllExtension</job-type>
```